# How can I update and divide column values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with two columns. In the first column `X` there are numbers from 1 to 10000. The second column `Y` is empty. This is how I set this up:

```
create table test1 (
  x number,
  y number
);

begin
  for l in 1..10000 LOOP
    insert into test1(x)
    values(l);
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
```

My first question is: I need to use an update statement to set the values of column `Y` in the reverse order to those in column `X`, i.e. from 10000 to 1. The row with X=1 needs to have Y=10000; the row with X=2 needs to name Y=9999; etc. How can I do that?

My second question is: how can I do a math operation (SQL or PL/SQL) 
which will leave in the column only those numbers which can be divided to 17?

Comment: If your current objective is to learn PL/SQL, and you use this just for practice, **say so** in your post, to avoid all the unneeded questions. Everyone is correct that all of this should be done in SQL; the only meaningful exception is if you are doing this for learning purposes and right now you are learning PL/SQL, not SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the divisible by 17, use [mod()](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/mod.php)

```
where mod(x,17) = 0 -- remainder (MOD) when divided by 17 = 0
```

Comment: thank you awesome can you give me example in pl / sql also )

Answer (score 2):

Answer to first question:

```
update test1
set y = 10001 - x
;

commit;
```

Comment: @Смок Белью - Why you need  pl/sql if pure SQL can do job?

Comment: @СмокБелью. Well the lesson is, don't do it in loops (PL/SQL or any other language) if you can do it in pure SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need PL/SQL or an update statement:

```
INSERT INTO test1 ( x, y )
  SELECT CASE MOD( lvl, 17 )
           WHEN 0
           THEN lvl * 3 -- Your "math operation"
           ELSE lvl
           END,
         10001 - lvl
  FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL AS lvl
           FROM DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000 );

COMMIT;
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO test1 ( x, y )
WITH cte ( lvl ) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT lvl + 1
  FROM   cte
  WHERE  lvl < 10000
)
SELECT CASE MOD( lvl, 17 )
         WHEN 0
         THEN lvl * 3 -- Your "math operation"
         ELSE lvl
       END,
       10001 - lvl
FROM   cte;
```

But if you need PL/SQL then you can just wrap it in an anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
  upper_bound CONSTANT NUMBER := 10000;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test1 ( x, y )
    SELECT CASE MOD( lvl, 17 )
             WHEN 0
             THEN lvl * 3 -- Your "math operation"
             ELSE lvl
             END,
           upper_bound + 1 - lvl
    FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL AS lvl
             FROM DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= upper_bound );

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple SQL query whoich will suffice your problem. Hope it helps.

```
MERGE INTO TEST1 USING
( SELECT X,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by 1 ASC) Y FROM TEST1 ORDER BY 1 DESC
)a ON (TEST1.X =a.X )
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET TEST1.Y = DECODE(MOD(A.Y,17),0,A.Y,NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, if you need it in PL/SQL

```
begin
  update test1
  set y = 10001 - x;
end;
/
commit;
```

Comment: Put a lable "edit" and merge this answer with your previous answer rather than posting another answer.